# Any tutorial for UI Automation of iPhone using Java Scripting?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to automate the `UI Testing` of my app.
Please tell me how to use `javascripting` to automate the process.
Dint get much information after searching on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main resource on Apple's site is the [UI Automation Reference Collection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) which lists the various interfaces, etc. available.

If you click the "more" link at the top of the above link a brief overview is provided, although I'd recommend at least a quick read of a blog such as "[How Do I Perform UI Automation Testing in iOS 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/UI_Automation_Testing.aspx)" over on [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com).

Answer (score 3):

The following is a place for beginners.
http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation

Answer (score 1):

One place to look is the [UI Automation Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009771-CH1-SW1). It is not really a tutorial but a reference.

In the [Instruments User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW1) you can read about how to run the scripts. It also walks you through how to script access to elements using the Recepies sample code.